# Decomposition of $(3)\subseteq \mathcal O_K$. Minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{19}$ which gives the integral basis.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, primary-decomposition

Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{19}$, $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and ring of integer is given $\mathcal O_K$.

Now I want to calculate some prime decomposition. However, in Marcus Number Fields' notes, since extension degree $3$ we cannot do the factoring $$x^3-19\equiv \cdots \mod 3$$

For the ideal $(3)\mathcal O_K$

My idea is, if possible, to find another minimum polynomial which gives the root $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{19}$ but also gives the other conjugates such that $\mathcal O_K$ and $\mathbb Z[\sqrt[3]{19}]$ meets.

So how to construct such polynomial?

I tried to factor with silly fashion, using integral basis of $\mathcal O_K$ of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{19})$ $$\mathcal O_K=\mathbb Z\left[1,\alpha,\frac{\alpha^2+\alpha+1}{3} \right]$$

as $$\left(x-1 \right)\left(x-\alpha \right)\left( x-\frac{\alpha^2+\alpha+1}{3}\right)\not\in \mathbb Z[x]$$

So how to calculate decomposition of $(3)$ in this cubic field?

Comment: Your $\mathcal O_K=\mathbb Z[\sqrt[3]{19}]$ indicates a misunderstanding. What is the minimal polynomial of $\frac{\alpha^2+\alpha+1}3$?

Comment: Hint: find an abstract ring $R$ (with “generators and relations”) isomorphic  to $O_K$ (you already have an integral basis, it shouldn’t be too hard), then study the ring $R/3R$.

Comment: Minimal polynomial is $x^3-x^2-6x-12$ but can it show that $\mathcal O_K=\mathbb Z[(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)/3]$?

Comment: Can you find an integer polynomial such that $P((1+\alpha+\alpha^2)/3)=\alpha$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your suggestion, the real root $\beta$ of $x^3-x^2-6x-12$ gives $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{19})$. The absolute value of the discriminant of the basis generated by $\beta$ is $4332$, thus $[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}(\beta)]$ is 2 (because the actual discriminant is $4332/4$).

Since $3\nmid{[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}(\beta)]}$ we can apply the Dedekind-Kummer theorem:

$$x^3-x^2-6x-12\equiv{x^2(x-1)}\mod3.$$

Thus, $(3)=(3,\beta)^2(3, \beta-1)$.

Comment: i am a bit stupid, so can you elaborate how you found/calculate the index?

Comment: BY standard means, we know that $\mathbb{Z}(\beta)$ is not the full ring of integers. There is a lemma, which allows us to say that if we add an element of the form $$\gamma=\frac{a_1+a_2\beta+a_3\beta^2}{2},$$ where -1<a_i<2 we will get the full ring of integers. This factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ tells us that as additive groups $[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\beta]]=2$. Think of it as the following: as an additive subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}$ has index 2 in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Are these ideals on the right handside principal?

Comment: @BobDobbs, the answer to your question may be found here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874504/class-number-of-mathbbq-sqrt319-and-hilbert-class-field).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't saw this link. I saw the one about the  cube root of 17. I found the minimal polynomial myself in this question. Then, why is the ring of integers NOT $\Bbb{Z}[\beta]$ but $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$? And why do we divide the polynomial discriminant by 4? It takes time to find out these things...

Comment: @BobDobbs, here are notes from my brilliant lecturer [link](https://cbirkbeck.github.io/test2/sect0011.html). Hope you will find them useful.

Comment: @JonIm Nope. They are simple.